# How can I add a string to an array when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, typed.js

**These are my strings and their speeds at which they will be displayed**

```
var typed = new Typed(".auto-input", {
        strings: ["Hi, blahblahblah.", "blahblahblah...", "...blahblahblah?"],
        typeSpeed: 75,
        backSpeed: 75,
        loop: true
    });
```

**This is my code for when my checkbox is checked**

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
});
```

**I tried an if statement**

```
if (document.body.classList.toggle('dark')) {
  typed.push(["lorem"]);
}
```

But then i realized, i think i need to select the "strings" in my "typed" vaiable. I'm not quite sure how to do that. I apologize in advance for any mistakes, this is my first question posted on StackOverflow.

Comment: What is `Typed`? It is obviously nothing that is built-in in browsers.

Comment: i watched a tutorial where i had to link this script tag in my html file `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typed.js@2.0.12"></script>` and then add the javascript which i wrote above

Comment: It looks like you cannot simply redefine your `typed.strings` once you instanciated your `typed` object. You would have to `.destroy()` and rebuild it, as [explained here](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/issues/312).

Comment: alright i will try that. thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

As you want to push `"lorem"` into `strings` inside `Typed`, your if statement should look like:

```
if (document.body.classList.toggle('dark')) {
  typed.strings.push("lorem");
}
```